# Python API for Crimson Hexagon

Tags: python, api, pandas

I'd like some feedback on the readability, style, and potential problems or issues. In particular I'm not too happy with how I handle ratelimits.

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import date
from flatten_json import flatten
from tqdm import tnrange as trange
from time import sleep

class CrimsonHexagonClient(object):
    """Interacts with the Crimson Hexagon API to retrieve post data (twitter ids
    etc.) from a configured monitor.

    Docs:
        https://apidocs.crimsonhexagon.com/v1.0/reference

     Args:
        username (str): Username on website.
        password (str): Password on website.
        monitor_id (str): id of crimson monitor.
    """

    def __init__(self, username, password, monitor_id):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.monitor_id = monitor_id
        self.base = 'https://api.crimsonhexagon.com/api/monitor'
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.ratelimit_refresh = 60
        self._auth()

    def _auth(self):
        """Authenticates a user using their username and password through the
        authenticate endpoint.
        """
        url = 'https://forsight.crimsonhexagon.com/api/authenticate?'

        payload = {
            'username': self.username,
            'password': self.password
        }

        r = self.session.get(url, params=payload)
        j_result = r.json()
        self.auth_token = j_result["auth"]
        print('-- Authenticated --')
        return

    def make_endpoint(self, endpoint):
        return '{}/{}?'.format(self.base, endpoint)

    def get_data_from_endpoint(self, from_, to_, endpoint):
        """Hits the designated endpoint (volume/posts) for a specified time period.
        The ratelimit is burned through ASAP and then backed off for one minute.
        """
        endpoint = self.make_endpoint(endpoint)
        from_, to_ = str(from_), str(to_)
        payload = {
            'auth': self.auth_token,
            'id': self.monitor_id,
            'start': from_,
            'end': to_,
            'extendLimit': 'true',
            'fullContents': 'true'
        }

        r = self.session.get(endpoint, params=payload)
        self.last_response = r

        ratelimit_remaining = r.headers['X-RateLimit-Remaining']

        # If the header is empty or 0 then wait for a ratelimit refresh.
        if (not ratelimit_remaining) or (float(ratelimit_remaining) < 1):
            print('Waiting for ratelimit refresh...')
            sleep(self.ratelimit_refresh)

        return r

    def get_dates_from_timespan(self, r_volume, max_documents=10000):
        """Divides the time period into chunks of less than 10k where possible.
        """
        # If the count is less than max, just return the original time span.
        if r_volume.json()['numberOfDocuments'] <= max_documents:
            l_dates = [[pd.to_datetime(r_volume.json()['startDate']).date(),
                       pd.to_datetime(r_volume.json()['endDate']).date()]]
            return l_dates

        # Convert json to df for easier subsetting & to calculate cumulative sum.
        df = pd.DataFrame(r_volume.json()['volume'])
        df['startDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startDate'])
        df['endDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['endDate'])

        l_dates = []

        while True:
            df['cumulative_sum'] = df['numberOfDocuments'].cumsum()

            # Find the span whose cumulative sum is below the threshold.
            df_below = df[df['cumulative_sum'] <= max_documents]

            # If there are 0 rows under threshold.
            if (df_below.empty):
                # If there are still rows left, use the first row.
                if len(df) > 0:
                    # This entry will have over 10k, but we can't go more
                    # granular than one day.
                    df_below = df.iloc[0:1]
                else:
                    break

            # Take the first row's start date and last row's end date.
            from_ = df_below['startDate'].iloc[0].date()
            to_ = df_below['endDate'].iloc[-1].date()

            l_dates.append([from_, to_])

            # Reassign df to remaining portion.
            df = df[df['startDate'] >= to_]

        return l_dates

    def plot_volume(self, r_volume):
        """Plots a time-series chart with two axes to show the daily and cumulative
        document count.
        """
        # Convert r to df, fix datetime, add cumulative sum.
        df_volume = pd.DataFrame(r_volume.json()['volume'])
        df_volume['startDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df_volume['startDate'])
        df_volume['endDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df_volume['endDate'])
        df_volume['cumulative_sum'] = df_volume['numberOfDocuments'].cumsum()

        fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
        ax2 = ax1.twinx()

        df_volume['numberOfDocuments'].plot(ax=ax1, style='b-')
        df_volume['cumulative_sum'].plot(ax=ax2, style='r-')

        ax1.set_ylabel('Number of Documents')
        ax2.set_ylabel('Cumulative Sum')

        h1, l1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
        h2, l2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
        ax1.legend(h1+h2, l1+l2, loc=2)

        plt.show()

        return

    def make_data_pipeline(self, from_, to_):
        """Combines the functionsin this class to make a robust pipeline, that 
        loops through each day in a time period. Data is returned as a dataframe.
        """

        # Get the volume over time data.
        r_volume = self.get_data_from_endpoint(from_, to_, 'volume')
        print('There are approximately {} documents.'.format(r_volume.json()['numberOfDocuments']))
        self.plot_volume(r_volume)

        # Carve up time into buckets of volume <10k.
        l_dates = self.get_dates_from_timespan(r_volume)

        data = []

        for i in trange(len(l_dates), leave=False):
            from_, to_ = l_dates[i]

            # Pull posts.
            r_posts = self.get_data_from_endpoint(from_, to_, 'posts')
            if r_posts.ok and (r_posts.json()['status'] != 'error'):
                j_result = json.loads(r_posts.content.decode('utf8'))
                data.extend(j_result['posts'])

        l_flat= [flatten(d) for d in data]
        df = pd.DataFrame(l_flat)

        return df

if __name__ == "__main__":


    # Credentials.
    username = 'xxxxx'
    password = 'xxxxx'

    # Monitor id - taken from URL on website.
    monitor_id = '123'

    # Instantiate client.
    crimson_api = CrimsonHexagonClient(username, password, monitor_id)

    from_ = date(2017, 1, 1)
    to_   = date(2017, 6, 30)

    # Combine class functions into a typical workflow.
    df = crimson_api.make_data_pipeline(from_, to_)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### [Readability & Style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

**Imports**

Remove the modules that you're not using (`dateutil`).
Imports should be grouped in the following order:

1. standard library imports
2. related third party imports
3. local application/library specific imports

**Code layout**

You should surround top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines.

*Whitespace in Expressions and Statements*

**Avoid** extraneous whitespaces before/after any operator (in your case, `=`) and between two lines of code.

**Comments**

You have some comments which doesn't add any value to your code. Get rid of them. (E.g: `# Credentials.`, `# Instantiate client.`)

---

#### Should you use OOP ?

You've created all your code by using a class but you didn't actually make use of it. 80% of your methods are *static* which makes me think you shouldn't need to use a class . Try to reorganise your code by splitting it into smaller functions and create classes only if you need to communicate state between your methods or you need one of the OOP principles (inheritance, polymorphism etc). *PS: As a side note, this is entirely subjective*

---

#### More on the code

- You're not using `self.last_response` anywhere. Remove it.
- In `_auth` and `plot_volume` methods, the `return` statement is redundant. Remove it.
- In `make_data_pipeline` method, don't create useless variables. Instead, you can directly return `pd.DataFrame(l_flat)`.
- You don't need parentheses here: `if (df_below.empty)`.
- You should really add some `try/except` blocks at least when you're authenticating against the API and let the user know if something went wrong or not.